# Testing a method using recursion in binary search tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

This `toRoot` method is supposed to return a list containing all the keys in the tree between the parameter `key` and the root. I have used a `System.out.println` statement in both the class and the junit test method. Why are the outputs of the two print statements different? The output printed in the `toRoot` method is what I want, but I am printing only the root in the junit test method. How do I fix this?

```
public List<K> toRoot(K key) {
        List<K> list=new LinkedList<K>();
        int i = key.compareTo(this.key);
        if(i == 0){
            list.add(this.key);
        }
        else if(i < 0){
            left.toRoot(key);
            list.add(this.key);
        }
        else if(i > 0){
            right.toRoot(key);
            list.add(this.key);
        }   
        System.out.print(list); //prints "i o n p s z i"...these are the desired 
        //outputs of the two assertEquals combined together
        return list;
    }
```

---

JUnit Testing

```
@Test public void testToRoot() {
    Tree<Character, Integer> tree = tree1();
    System.out.print(tree.toRoot('o')); //prints 'i'
    assertEquals("i", tree.toRoot('i'));
    assertEquals("o n p s z i", tree.toRoot('o'));
}
private static Tree<Character, Integer> tree1() {
    Tree<Character, Integer> tree = EmptyTree.getInstance();

    tree= tree.add('i', 1);
    tree= tree.add('z', 2);
    tree= tree.add('e', 3);
    tree= tree.add('s', 4);
    tree= tree.add('p', 5);
    tree= tree.add('n', 6);
    tree= tree.add('b', 7);
    tree= tree.add('h', 8);
    tree= tree.add('o', 9);
    tree= tree.add('f', 10);

    return tree;
}
```

---

additional details:
The tree class is an interface that the `NotEmptyTree` class implements and includes an overwritten `toRoot`.

```
public NonEmptyTree<K, V> add(K key, V value);
```

Here is the overwritten add method in the `NotEmptyTree` class

```
public NotEmptyTree<K, V> add(K key, V value) {
        if(key.compareTo(this.key) == 0){
            this.value = value;
        }else if(key.compareTo(this.key) < 0){
            left = left.add(key, value);
        }else{
            right = right.add(key, value);
        }
        return this;    
    }
```

Letters near the front of the alphabet are smaller than those towards the end. In this case, `'i'` is the parent node of `'e'` and `'z'`. `'z'` has a left child of `'s'`, which has left child of `'p'`, which has left child of `'n'`, which has right child of `'o'`. `'e'` has left child of `'b'`, which has right child of `'h'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `toRoot` method may be printing a string to `System.out`, but it does not **return** a `String`. Instead, it returns a `List`. Thus your assertion is going to be always false because a `String` does not equal a `List`.

If you want to compare against a `String`, then you'll need to write a function that converts a `List<K>` into a space delimited `String` and then invoke that function before calling `assertEquals`.

Another alternative, would be to use a [Hamcrest](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/)-style matcher like [`contains`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains%28E...%29):

```
assertThat(tree.toRoot(), contains('o', 'n', 'p', 's', 'z', 'i'));
```

Note that despite the name, the `contains` does an in-order check, so even if the keys were out of order this test would fail, which should give identical behavior to the `assertEquals` check you were making before.